# ImageView Location

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I set the location of the ImageView, for instance i want it at x = 150 and y = 150?

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageViewYellow" 
 android:src="@drawable/yellocircle" 
 android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, consider that you don't know what screen size your user will be running your application on, so just placing it at 150px top-left will never get you a predictable result. You could use a RelativeLayout to do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#808080"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        />          
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which gives:

[image: Four Aligned Corners]

Keep in mind that this would fall apart if the images got too large to fit side by side. You could always write something in code to draw the ImageViews at a certain screen proportion, scale them down, and just set the layout_gravity of the ImageViews inside a FrameLayout to `top|left`, `top|right`, `bottom|left`, and `bottom|right`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of view group it is in. If you use an [`AbsoluteLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) (deprecated), you can specify it using the `x` and `y` parameters of `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams`. With a `FrameLayout`, you can control the position using the `layout_margin*` parameters. Alternatively, you can define your own custom layout manager by subclassing ViewGroup.

Comment: How can I use the FrameLayout?, i need to place 4 circles like this (each circle is a picture)  middle top, left , right, middle bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 android:layout_x="150px"
 android:layout_y="150px"
```

But Ted Hoop is right, it will depend on parent elements specifications.